# WPF Passing Data Between Clone Windows

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a MainWindow and there is a button in MainWindow to open ClientWindow.

```
private void btnMakeClient_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ClientWindow window = new ClientWindow();           
            window.Show();
        }
```

Forexample; if i 3 times click, then it opens 3 ClientWindow (chatWindow). **How can i pass data(text) between these clone windows?** I mean i write "hi how are you?" in a ClientWindow (chatWindow) and it appears in another windows too.

I thought that if i pass data(text) from ClientWindow with a MainWindow constructor and get it back with ClientWindow constructor would solve my problem but it did not. Here is my code

MainWindow:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public string TextContent { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public MainWindow(string txtContext)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TextContent = txtContext;
            ClientWindow window = new ClientWindow(TextContent);
        }

        private void btnMakeClient_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            
            ClientWindow window = new ClientWindow();
            window.Show();
        }
    }
```

ClientWindow:

```
 public partial class ClientWindow : Window
    {
    public string Chatcontent { get; set; }

    public ClientWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ClientWindow(string chatContent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Chatcontent = chatContent;
        if (chatContent != string.Empty)
        {
            this.txtContent.Text += Environment.NewLine + Chatcontent;
            txtChat.Clear();
        }            
    }

    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow window = new MainWindow(txtChat.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: @VisualBean In case of Observer pattern subject would be MainWindow which can notify ChildWindows (observers) if something changes in it. In this requirement one of the observers is going to change the state and not the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where MVVM shines. Create a ViewModel object that contain a String property and a Command to add text to this property and then in client windows just call this command with the text to add as parameter.

Note that I use DelegateCommand as described [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/delegatecommand.html) but you can also use RelayCommand.

ViewModel

```
public class YourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private String _textContent;
    public String TextContent {
        get {return _textContent;}
        set {
            _textContent = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TextContent");
        }
    }

    private DelegateCommand _cmdAddTextToChat;
    /// <summary>
    /// Add text to TextContent
    /// </summary>
    public DelegateCommand CmdAddTextToChat {
        get { return _cmdAddTextToChat ?? (_cmdAddTextToChat = new DelegateCommand(AddTextToChat)); }
    }

    private void AddTextToChat(Object parameter) {
        TextContent += (String)parameter;
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private YourViewModel _vm = new YourViewModel ();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MainWindow(string txtContext)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _vm.TextContent = txtContext;
        ClientWindow window = new ClientWindow() {DataContext = _vm};
    }

    private void btnMakeClient_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        ClientWindow window = new ClientWindow() {DataContext = _vm};
        window.Show();
    }
}


public partial class ClientWindow : Window

    public ClientWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();  
    }
}
```

ClientWindow xaml:

```
<DockPanel>

    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox x:Name="InputTextBox"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding CmdAddTextToChat, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=InputTextBox, Path=Text}">
    </StackPanel>
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding TextContent, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

**Edit: without DataContext**

If you don't want to set the DataContext you can use another DP (Tag could be used, you can also create a new one):

```
#region ViewModelObject 

public YourViewModel ViewModelObject
{
    get { return (YourViewModel)GetValue(ViewModelObjectProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ViewModelObjectProperty, value); }
}

private readonly static FrameworkPropertyMetadata ViewModelObjectMetadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata {
};

public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelObjectProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("ViewModelObject", typeof(YourViewModel), typeof(ClientWindow), ViewModelObjectMetadata);
#endregion
```

And in your click event

```
private void btnMakeClient_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    ClientWindow window = new ClientWindow() {YourViewModelObject = _vm};
    window.Show();
}
```

Comment: Is there any possible solution without a datacontext? Thank you

Comment: @AttilaAlan you can create a DP for this purpose. Or a simple property that notifies OnPropertyChanged. Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class for message with Text property and implement INotifyPropertyChanged in this class. Then store an instance of this class in MainWindow and pass it to constructor of your ClientWindow. Set it to DataContext and create a binding to Text property (in TextBox, for example). When you update Text property the other windows will see this changes.

Comment: This should really be a comment unless you can post a working code to support your solution. Code is also required because you are talking MVVM way and OP is doing WPF in Win Forms way.

Comment: @nikhilvartak I just want to give a right direction. I think it's more useful then a full solution that you can just copy-paste (especially for an author who looks like beginner)